# Prove that if $T$ a normal linear transformation and invertible, then $T^{-1}$ is normal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, spectral-theory

The question is: Prove that if $T$ a normal linear transformation and invertible, then $T^{-1}$ is normal. Then I have to find the spectral decomposition of $T^{-1}$.
At first I tried to prove it by definition: $T$ is normal so $TT^*=T^*T$ and I marked $S=T^{-1}$. So $ST=TS=I$.

Now I tried to prove that $SS^*=S^*S$ but didn't succeed by now. Many thanks to the helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $S=T^{-1}$; then $S^*=(T^{-1})^*=(T^*)^{-1}$.

Therefore

$$
SS^*=T^{-1}(T^*)^{-1}=(T^*T)^{-1}
$$

Can you go on from here?

For the spectral decomposition, observe that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\lambda\ne0$, so, for an eigenvector $v$ relative to $\lambda$ we have
\begin{gather}
Tv=\lambda v\\
STv=S(\lambda v)\\
v=\lambda Sv\\
Sv=\lambda^{-1}v
\end{gather}
and therefore $E_T(\lambda)=E_S(\lambda^{-1})$ (denoting with $E_A(\lambda)$ the eigenspace of the matrix $A$ relative to the eigenvalue $\lambda$). So it should be easy to write down the spectral decomposition of $S$.

Comment: yes thanks you. do you how to find the spectral decomposition of T^-1?

Comment: @CnR The eigenvalues of $S$ are the inverses of the eigenvalues of $T$ and the eigenspaces are the same.

Comment: How do we know it?

Comment: @CnR I added a note